# Modeling software using Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml, modeling

I am brand new to modeling software (my greatest reference so far has been the Wikipedia page on UML). Are there any free tools that I can use with Eclipse to auto-generate diagrams?

Thanks

EDIT:Just to clarify, I am not necessarily looking for the 'right' solution, as I don't have  a specific problem. I am just trying to see what is out there that other people use!

EDIT: Tried eUML2 . Worked ok. It destroys the look of the code (if you have ever seen auto-generated HTML code or the code created by NetBeans, image that now) by adding comments everywhere. The background says evaluation in huge letters, which is also annoying. The UML is decent, but definitely not standard. All in all, not what i'm looking for. On to something else...

EDIT: Tried UMLet. Works well, very easy to get the hang of. Unfortunately it does not auto-pull any information from the source code. Will likely leave it installed for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at [eUML](http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/). It creates [nice looking UML diagrams](http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/screenshots/). However, what I don't like with it is that it is very strictly connected to the source code and thus lacks some flexibility. Any change in the source code changes the diagrams and the other way around - and this is IMO not always desirable.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I am installing now. Good to know about that strict connection before I start playing around!

Comment: eUML is a crack of EclipseUML 2005 which is produced in China !! A member of the developer team left the company in 2005 with the full code and .....Be careful if you use eUML in your company because this is a copyright violation.

The main problem with eUML is that  you get EMF tags in your code. If you have a project and reverse it then all your code presentation is lost and full of tags are added in the code. A real mess !!  
EUML has only a graphical UML design with EMF tags but no UML model !!

Comment: Good to know. I made a hard copy of the (personal) project that I can safely mess up :)

Answer (score 0):

Check [Eclipse MDT (Model Developing Tools)](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=uml2)

Comment: Yea, I have been trying to install this from available software. Having trouble, but I got the UML2Tools to install so I am testing those. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You have plenty of UML tools with Galileo and will have UML tools for Helios in the next six months.
I am a paid customer so got today the Helios UML build from Omondo.Please note that if you are not a paid up customer then you will not be able to download the lastest Helios build !!

Comment: Strange, I just downloaded it and I have never paid anything? Anyways,  do you mind being more specific with the 'plenty of UML tools with Galileo'?

Comment: I just downloaded Eclipses Helios without paying a cent. I don't see how this helps answer the question here.

Comment: You pay for the Omondo UML plugin for Helios and not for the open source Helios project provided by the Eclipse foundation :-)